# Make .scn model to have front camera view

Tags: ios, iphone, model, scenekit, orthographic

We are creating iOS message extension app which is similar to Apple's Animoji app, we have created our own models (Some 3d faces) and we have .dae files for these models. We are converting these files to scn files in XCode by using option "Convert to scenkit scene file format (.scn)". When we see this scn file in XCode viewer, camera's Perspective view is shown for the model, and in this perspective view the face of the model looks thinner.  Once we tap on the Perspective option drop down and choose "Front" option, model's face is in correct posture and is in its normal shape. We want this shape to show in the app also while running, but everytime we show model only the thinner face (perspective view) is visible. Is there a way to set camera to front for the model programmatically ? Is there any specific step we need to take while exporting the dae file ? so that by default camera view is front only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "front" camera in the Xcode editor is an orthographic camera (its [`usesOrthographicProjection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436621-usesorthographicprojection?changes=_4&language=objc) is set to `YES`).

Alternatively you can change the `fieldOfView` or `focalLength` properties to reduce the amount of deformation due to perspective. You can find an illustration in this [post on the Photography site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/76335).

Comment: Thanks for directing in correct direction. Used following  camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
        camera.orthographicScale = 25

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an orthographic projection for the camera. To setup it correctly you can add some camera object to the scene graph in .scn XCode viewer and choose "camera" option in drop down list. Camera projection type is perspective by default therefore you should change it to orthographic.

P.S. can you share some screenshot of your 3d face? Is it better than Memoji?)